# How to create a background task which runs forever -Python FlaskSQLAlchemy

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to create a simple background task that runs forever. I will figure out a method of starting it at the same time as my web application written in Flask.

What I have so far is this:

```
import threading
from app.models import SkillTracker, UserAttributes
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import db
import time, math

class SkillTimer(threading.Thread, SkillTracker):
    def __init__(self, SkillTracker=SkillTracker):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.skillcheck = SkillTracker.query.filter_by(isactive=1).all()
    def run(self):
            # for x in range(1, 1+1):
            #     if x%1 == 0:
            #         print(x)
            # #print(x)
            time.sleep(1)
            self.skillcheck = SkillTracker.query.filter_by(isactive=1).all()

            if self.skillcheck != []:
                print(self.skillcheck)
                for record in self.skillcheck:
                    if record.isactive == 1:
                        if record.timesubmit + record.timetowait <= time.time():
                            user = UserAttributes.query.filter_by(user_id=record.userid).first()
                            if record.targetskill == 'int':
                                record.isactive = 0
                                user.intelligence += 1
                                db.session.commit()
                                print('User {} upgraded {}, level = {} -- {}'.format(user.user_id, record.targetskill,
                                                                                     user.intelligence, time.time()))
                            if record.targetskill == 'end':
                                record.isactive = 0
                                user.endurance += 1
                                db.session.commit()
                                print('User {} upgraded {}, level = {} -- {}'.format(user.user_id, record.targetskill,
                                                                                     user.endurance, time.time()))
                            if record.targetskill == 'str':
                                record.isactive = 0
                                user.strength += 1
                                db.session.commit()
                                print('User {} upgraded {}, level = {} -- {}'.format(user.user_id, record.targetskill,
                                                                                     user.strength, time.time()))
            else:
                pass
            self.skillcheck = None
            skilltime = SkillTimer()
            skilltime.run()


#while True:
skilltime = SkillTimer()
skilltime.run()
#skilltimer.run()
```

And this works perfectly as you would expect it to, however, I run into problems after it has runs more than ~950 times. I get a recursion error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\feuadal_kingdom\app\Skilltimer.py", line 52, in <module>
    skilltime.run()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\feuadal_kingdom\app\Skilltimer.py", line 47, in run
    skilltime.run()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\feuadal_kingdom\app\Skilltimer.py", line 47, in run
    skilltime.run()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\feuadal_kingdom\app\Skilltimer.py", line 47, in run
    skilltime.run()
  [Previous line repeated 923 more times]
  File "D:\Anaconda3\feuadal_kingdom\app\Skilltimer.py", line 46, in run
    skilltime = SkillTimer()
  File "<string>", line 4, in __init__
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state.py", line 414, in _initialize_instance
    manager.dispatch.init_failure(self, args, kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\state.py", line 411, in _initialize_instance
    return manager.original_init(*mixed[1:], **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\feuadal_kingdom\app\Skilltimer.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.skillcheck = SkillTracker.query.filter_by(isactive=1).all()
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2638, in all
    return list(self)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2790, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2813, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1046, in _execute_clauseelement
    if not self.schema_for_object.is_default else None)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 436, in compile
    return self._compiler(dialect, bind=bind, **kw)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 442, in _compiler
    return dialect.statement_compiler(dialect, self, **kw)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 435, in __init__
    Compiled.__init__(self, dialect, statement, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 216, in __init__
    self.string = self.process(self.statement, **compile_kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 242, in process
    return obj._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 81, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 1738, in visit_select
    text, select, inner_columns, froms, byfrom, kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 1822, in _compose_select_body
    t = select._whereclause._compiler_dispatch(self, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 81, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 1025, in visit_binary
    return self._generate_generic_binary(binary, opstring, **kw)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 1050, in _generate_generic_binary
    self, eager_grouping=eager_grouping, **kw)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\visitors.py", line 81, in _compiler_dispatch
    return meth(self, **kw)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 1183, in visit_bindparam
    name = self._truncate_bindparam(bindparam)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 1239, in _truncate_bindparam
    bind_name = self._truncated_identifier("bindparam", bind_name)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 1250, in _truncated_identifier
    anonname = name.apply_map(self.anon_map)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 4079, in apply_map
    return self % map_
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\_collections.py", line 729, in __missing__
    self[key] = val = self.creator(key)
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\compiler.py", line 1269, in _process_anon
    return derived + "_" + str(anonymous_counter)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
```

Which kills the process, and I wouldn't dare pass the exception as it's there for a reason.

My question is this, is there a way I can adapt this threaded class so that it can be run for infinite number of times?

I feel like this could be resolved by re-initiating the class thread each time, but again, I'm not entirely sure how to create these kind of infinite loops.

The only caveat is that at this time I'm only testing so any solutions should be interruptable by the keyboard please.

Please let me know if you need further clarity, there is not any errors in database models or flask routes, everything works perfectly as I want it to except this errors after it reaches the recursion limit. E.g. increasing the recursion limit will only delay the error, not resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change it like this:

```
import threading
from app.models import SkillTracker, UserAttributes
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from app import db
import time, math

class SkillTimer(threading.Thread, SkillTracker):
    def __init__(self, SkillTracker=SkillTracker):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.skillcheck = SkillTracker.query.filter_by(isactive=1).all()
    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.skillcheck = SkillTracker.query.filter_by(isactive=1).all()

            if self.skillcheck != []:
                print(self.skillcheck)
                for record in self.skillcheck:
                    if record.isactive == 1:
                        if record.timesubmit + record.timetowait <= time.time():
                            user = UserAttributes.query.filter_by(user_id=record.userid).first()
                            if record.targetskill == 'int':
                                record.isactive = 0
                                user.intelligence += 1
                                db.session.commit()
                                print('User {} upgraded {}, level = {} -- {}'.format(user.user_id, record.targetskill,
                                                                                     user.intelligence, time.time()))
                            if record.targetskill == 'end':
                                record.isactive = 0
                                user.endurance += 1
                                db.session.commit()
                                print('User {} upgraded {}, level = {} -- {}'.format(user.user_id, record.targetskill,
                                                                                     user.endurance, time.time()))
                            if record.targetskill == 'str':
                                record.isactive = 0
                                user.strength += 1
                                db.session.commit()
                                print('User {} upgraded {}, level = {} -- {}'.format(user.user_id, record.targetskill,
                                                                                     user.strength, time.time()))
            else:
                pass
            self.skillcheck = None


skilltime = SkillTimer()
skilltime.run()
```

Comment: Running this now, will let you know if we hit ~950 recursions. If we this works, I believe the problem can be atrributed to the amount of threads at one time or something like that. Will let you know and accept if this fixes the problem :) Thanks for the suggestion. So far so good.

Comment: I think you fixed it so thanks @codeglow will accept your answer.